# Get hard coded param from WPF UserControl to code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I 'm trying to do something really simple: I have a UserControl, where I want to pass a simple string parameter.

**WPF MessagePage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="MuchroomPhone.MessagePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MuchroomPhone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

//...
<PivotItem Header="Nouveaux">
                <local:MessageUC MessType="new"/>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="Lus" >
            <local:MessageUC MessType="read"/>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="Envoyés" >
            <local:MessageUC MessType="send"/>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="Tous" >
            <local:MessageUC MessType="all"/>
        </PivotItem>
//...
```

I want to get the MessType from the code behind of the MessageUC.

eg. : I want to get the string "new" in the MessageUC.xaml.cs

I've tried that so far:

**MessageUC.xaml**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MuchroomPhone.MessageUC"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MuchroomPhone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">
//I don't think the content of the UC is important for my issue, but if you wanted to I can give it too.
```

**MessageUC.xaml.cs**

```
 public sealed partial class MessageUC : UserControl
    {
        public string _messType;

        public string MessType
        {
           get{ return _messType;}
           set{this._messType = value;}
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Message> listMessages { get; set; }

        public MessageUC()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Debug.WriteLine(MessType);
            this.fetchUserData();           
        }
```

But the MessType string is empty...
Any ideas how to achieve that?

PS: I think there should be a way less verbose way for do that, so if you know a "simple" trick, would be great!
Thanks

EDIT: So If I use a simple property, it's should work? Cause I still have null on MessType...

I've also tried with a Dependency Property, and MessType is an empty string.

EDIT 2: I think I understand what is wrong. Actually MessType doesn't exist on MessageUC.xaml. So the code behind can't find it. Perhaps isn it possible to just pass variable to my Page MessagePage.xaml directly to the User Control MessageUC?

Comment: The constructor has not completed at that point so the value will always be the default specified int the Registered dependency property, which is String.Empty. Looking at that code, it should be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need is move fetchUserData to loaded event:

```
public sealed partial class MessageUC : UserControl
{
    public string MessType { get; set; }

    public MessageUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Debug.Writeline(MessType); //null
        Loaded += MessageUC_Loaded;
    }

    public void MessageUC_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Writeline(MessType); //new
        this.fetchUserData();
    }
}
```

DependencyProperty is not needed! Your original code doesn't work, because ctor in invoked before the property is set. DependecyProperty does not solve this, but enables databinding, styling, animating of the property.

Comment: I don't even need a property for MessType? Cause like that messType is undefined

Comment: sure you need to define the property. I have skipped it, because I only wanted to highlight different parts of the code, but I edited my answer. BTW undefined does not exist in C#. You are not able to compile code if you are trying to use something that was not defined.

Comment: Perfect, it's simple and it's works, love you <3 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You only need a DependencyProperty if you want to data bind to it. In your case you can just use a normal property.

Answer (score 0):

This is a set of instructions that *should* work. However you didn't show the definition of your control so the code below may need some modifications and adjustments.

So start with registering a dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty _messTypeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("_messType", typeof(String),
    typeof(MessageUC), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

public String _messType
{
    get { return GetValue(_messTypeProperty).ToString(); }
    set { SetValue(_messTypeProperty, value); }
}
```

Add a name to your control in XAML:

```
<UserrControl x:Class="myNamespace.MessageUC"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    x:Name="MyUserControl">
```

In the XAML definition of your MessageUC control, in the code where you implement `MessType` bind it to the property in the code behind. Point to your control using the name you added to the control definition:

```
MessType="{Binding Path=_messType, ElementName=MyUserControl}"
```

Comment: Yes, but where is the string I want to pass in Param? I want get the param from the XAML.

Comment: Sorry, you just lost me. My understanding of your problem: make possible to set messType on the MessageUC from XAML. If that's not the case can you please edit your question to make clearer what's exactly the problem?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it another shot this evening. Just a note, from the code you added it's actually a Page not a UserControl. Doubt it makes any difference though.

Comment: Yes it's a page, but it's from these page I want to call the UC, I will edit again and give the UC code, Thanks you!

Comment: Can you only show how you declare `messType` in XAML definition of your control? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what do you want I show you... messType is define on the XAML MessagePage, and I want to get the messType value from the code behind of MessageUC, so basicaly, messType isn't defined on MessageUC control;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81515/discussion-between-piotrwolkowski-and-julien-leray).